# Python: get item from list in list

Tags: python, list, element

How can I get an item from a list if that list is in a list? So if I have

```
mylist=[[range(4*(x-1)+1,4*(x-1)+5)]for x in range(1,5)]
```

then how can I retrieve the '1' from it? I always thought it was like

```
print mylist[0][0]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: do you get an error or just a value that you weren't expecting?

Answer (score 7):

That's actually a triple-nested list, because `range()` returns a list, and then you have it wrapped in `[]`.

Perhaps what you really wanted was...

```
mylist=[range(4*(x-1)+1,4*(x-1)+5) for x in range(1,5)]
```

At which point `mylist[0][0]` should do what you expect.

Comment: Keep in mind, that `range()` won't return a list in Python 3. You could use `list(range())` to make it work in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes, that's totally correct! I didn't realize that the list itself was the problem. Thanks a lot to all!

Answer (score 0):

Hate to be the Captain Obvious, but all you needed to do is just go 1 level deeper :)

```
>>> mylist=[[range(4*(x-1)+1,4*(x-1)+5)]for x in range(1,5)]
>>> mylist
[[[1, 2, 3, 4]], [[5, 6, 7, 8]], [[9, 10, 11, 12]], [[13, 14, 15, 16]]]
>>> mylist[0][0][0]
1
```